# Applying Bootstrap "table-striped" after creating table rows dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to ensure the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) `table-stripped` CSS style is applied to a table whose rows are added dynamically at runtime. For some reason, that I'm trying to get to the bottom of, I can't get this particular style to work so that my new rows are styled with the stripped look.

So if I have this HTML with `table-stripped` included:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading A</th>
            <th>Heading B</th>
            <th>Heading C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Then I run this JavaScript code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
    $('#table2 > tbody:last').before('<tr><td>' + i +'</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>');
}
```

I'll get my 5 new rows but they won't have the `table-stripped` style applied.

Even if I add the class manually after creating using this it makes no difference.

```
$('#table2').addClass('table-hover');
```

I've created a [jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UyrDg/1/) so you can see this running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use *append* to **tbody** instead of *before*. The way it is now, the rows are added outside of **tbody**.

Changing just this line:

```
$('#table2 > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + i +'</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>');
```

Seems to make your jsFiddle work.

Answer (score 4):

Change to `.append()` to the `<tbody>` and also fix your missing closing `</tr>`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UyrDg/3/)

```
$('#table2 > tbody').append('<tr><td>' + i +'</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>');
```

By using `.before()` you were inserting the rows before the tbody which caused the style not to be applied because the Bootstrap style targets rows that are children of the tbody.

Comment: Thanks @MrCode for your contribution.