# Apply table classes on ajax response

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatables

I have applied classes on my `<table>` and I am creating my rows from AJAX response in JSON. My issue is, listing is shown for 3 different radios selection, but the table classes are not being applied on the inserted rows so it escapes the pagination classes data. How can I rectify this? I searched a lot, and asked a lot many forums but could not get any outcome.

`<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap"   cellspacing="0" width="100%">`

Any help or advice will be welcomed and appreciated.

```
<?php include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ; ?>
<?php
ob_start();                                 

$errmsg         =   "" ;
$module_id      =   '';
$query          =   '';
$date_from      =   '';
$date_to        =   '';
$status ='';
$check ='';
$disabled='';
$row='';

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type = 3 AND status = 0 AND registration_type = 0";
?>

<div class="container pagecontainer">
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">
         <?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">
        <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
            <div class="panel-heading">Candidate Approval</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">
                    <form id="selection" method="GET" >
                        <input type='radio'  name='users' value='unapproved' checked /> Unapproved Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type='radio'  name='users' value='approved' /> Approved Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type='radio' id='show' name='users' value='all'  /> All Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap"   cellspacing="0" width="100%">           
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>S.No.</th>
                  <th>Email ID</th>
                  <th> Reference ID</th>  
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Mobile No.</th>
                  <th>Registration Date</th>
                  <th>Check for Approval 
                  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="all_check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> class="checkbox" value= "<?php //echo $row['id']; ?>"> </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id=datashow></tbody> 
                        </table> 

                        <input type="submit" name ="all_send" value="Approve" style="display: none; float: right;"  id="one" class="btn btn-success">

                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/row-->
    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $('#selection').change
    (


        function() 
        {

            var selected_value = $("input[name='users']:checked").val();

            $.ajax
            ( 
                {
                    url: "report_ajax.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { selected_value : selected_value },

                    success: function(response)
                    {
                         console.log(response);

                            var len = response.length;
                             $("#datashow").empty();
                       for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                             var id = response[i].id;
                             var email = response[i].email;
                             var employee_id = response[i].employee_id;
                             var first_name = response[i].first_name;
                             var middle_name = response[i].middle_name;
                             var last_name = response[i].last_name;
                             var mobile = response[i].mobile;
                             var created_on = response[i].created_on;
                             var disabled = response[i].disabled;
                             var users = response[i].users;

                var tr_str = 
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + employee_id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + first_name + "&nbsp;" + middle_name + "&nbsp;" + last_name + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + mobile + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + created_on + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'"  + disabled +  "value= '"  + id +  "' class='checkbox' id='select_all' ></td>" +
                      "<input type='hidden' value='"  + id +  "' name='user_id' id='user_id' >" +
                    "</tr>" ;


                $("#datashow").append(tr_str);
            }

                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
  $('input[name="check[]"]').click(function() {
    var checkedChbx = $('[type=checkbox]:checked');
    if (checkedChbx.length > 0) {
      $('#one').show();
    } else {
      $('#one').hide();
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  var $submit = $("#one");
  $submit.hide();
  var $cbs = $('input[name="all_check[]"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="check[]"]').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
    $submit.toggle($(this).is(":checked")); //use this to get the current clicked element 
  });

}); 

</script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
      var select_all = document.getElementById("select_all"); //select all checkbox
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox"); //checkbox items

//select all checkboxes
select_all.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) { 
        checkboxes[i].checked = select_all.checked;
    }
});


for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){ //".checkbox" change 
        //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
        if(this.checked == false){
            select_all.checked = false;
        }
        //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
        if(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked').length == checkboxes.length){
            select_all.checked = true;
        }
    });
}


    </script>

    <script>
// set users via PHP

var users = "<?php if (isset($_POST['users'])) echo $_POST['users']; ?>";
// update the HTML without interfering with other scripts
(function(users){
  // check if PH
  if (users.length) {
    // update the radio option...
    var inputTag = document.querySelector('input[value="'+users+'"]');
    if (inputTag)
      inputTag.checked = true;
    // if users is "all"
    // hide the last TD of every column
    if (users == "all") {
      var lastTh = document.querySelector('tr th:last-child');
      lastTh.style.display = "none";
      var allLastTds = document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');
      for (var i = 0; i< allLastTds.length; i++) {
        allLastTds[i].style.display="none";
      }
    }



    if (users == "approved") {
      thInputTag = document.getElementById("select_all");
      thInputTag.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
     var form = document.querySelector("form");
    var inputName = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="users"]');
    for (var j=0; j<inputName.length; j++)
      inputName[j].onclick=function(){
        form.submit();
        };
        }
        })(users);

</script>
```

**report_ajax.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();

  require("../includes/config.php"); 
  require("../classes/Database.class.php"); 
  $db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);  

  $return_arr = array();
  $status=''; 

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "selected_value");
    if (isset($value))
    {
      $users = $value;
    } 
    else 
    {
      $users='';
    }

  switch ($users)
  {
    case "all":
      $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";       
      break;
    case "approved":
      $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =1";   
      break;
  }

  $sq = $db->query($sqlQuery);

  if ($db->affected_rows > 0) 
  {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) 
    {
      $disabled = '';
      if ($status == '1') 
      {
        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
      }

      $id = $row['id'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
      $first_name = $row['first_name'];
      $middle_name = $row['middle_name'];
      $last_name = $row['last_name'];
      $mobile = $row['mobile'];
      $created_on1 = $row['created_on'];
      $created_on = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on1));

      $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
        "email" => $email,
        "employee_id" => $employee_id,
        "first_name" => $first_name,
        "middle_name" => $middle_name,
        "last_name" => $last_name,
        "mobile" => $mobile,
        "created_on" => $created_on
        "disabled" => $disabled
      );
    }
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: Which of your element inside table misses the styles that should be present ?

Comment: Thanks for time. As you can see I am appending my response on `<tbody>`. And the `<tbody>` falls under my `<table>` tag.

Comment: my guess is that the inserted rows do not appear striped for example as defined with the table class `table-striped`, but you want them to appear striped. Am I correct?

Comment: Do you have the `bootstrap` css included in your page ?

Comment: I want the result list to have all the classes applied to them so that my checkboxes and pagination works.

Comment: Yes its bootstrap css and jquery files.

Comment: The formatting is really poor, it's hard to read. all double spaced.

Comment: Check this: `tr_str ` variable, there is no class to any HTML element here except the checkbox.

Comment: I am sorry for the poor indentation.

Comment: Then how it should be? Can you please put that line of code .

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671231/applying-bootstrap-table-striped-after-creating-table-rows-dynamically) seems to be asking about the very same thing, but the solution that was accepted seems to be not working for you (you already use `.append()`)

Comment: You know you can return HTML inside of JSON, if all you need is the HTML then it's preferable performance wise to just send the HTML instead creating a big array, sending it then processing it into HTML on the clientside. It's less work on the browser, basically.  See you take `$row` convert it to `$return_arr` send it and then convert it to HTML, you can just do the HTML and skip all those extra steps.  Even if you need some data, you can call an item `data.html` and put all the html in there.

Comment: From the styling perspective, whats missing? Or is it only pagination and checkboxes that don't work ?

Comment: On a sidenote: please note that you are creating multiple elements with the same id (`id='select_all'`, `id='user_id'`).

Comment: pagination and checkbox are my concern @rach8garg

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am sorry I could not get you. Can you please specify in my code.

Comment: @Cashbee Thanks for time. Yes I have already used `append()`

Comment: You are doing way to much "localization" , you take `$row` transfer it to `$return_arr` send it to the browser, take it from `data` localize it, then put it in HTML and output is. You can just create the HTML strait from the row and send it as one big string. and skip all that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am naïve in jquery and javascript actually. So a bit difficult to make out from what you are saying. I am sorry for it. @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: It would be great if you send the compiled HTML template from backend and append it at once rather than iterate in client end. Try if pagination and checkboxes work in that case.

Comment: How it can be done. Can you provide some reference to it

Comment: just build the HTML in the PHP (in the while loop `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) `) instead of javascript. then return/echo the HTML string.

Comment: @Anand  `<tbody id=datashow> </tbody>` as I said at the bottom of my answer, might want to fix that.

Comment: Done that. No help. Same results. @Cashbee :(

Comment: No it didn't. @rach8garg Have been searching for solution since three days now. Completely hopeless now.

Comment: Your problem is data table plugin you are using perhaps. Its not applying to the table after rows are added. Try adding some static rows to table. Check if that works. Next step after that.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I really appreciate. I sent values like , `  "<tr>" +
                      "<td>1</td>" +
                      "<td>email@gmail.com</td>" +
                      "<td>TEST</td>" +
                      "<td>XXX&nbsp;XXXX&nbsp;YYY</td>" +
                      "<td>987654321</td>" +
                      "<td>30-02-2018</td>" +
                      "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value= '1' class='checkbox' id='select_all' ></td>" + "<input type='hidden' value='1' name='user_id' id='user_id' >" + "</tr>"  ;` but no change.Goes in loop for records.

Comment: Something else can be done? @rach8garg

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what your issue is, but what I was saying was instead of this:

Your PHP code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) 
    {
      $disabled = '';
      if ($status == '1') 
      {
        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
      }

      $id = $row['id'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
      $first_name = $row['first_name'];
      $middle_name = $row['middle_name'];
      $last_name = $row['last_name'];
      $mobile = $row['mobile'];
      $created_on1 = $row['created_on'];
      $created_on = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on1));

      $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
        "email" => $email,
        "employee_id" => $employee_id,
        "first_name" => $first_name,
        "middle_name" => $middle_name,
        "last_name" => $last_name,
        "mobile" => $mobile,
        "created_on" => $created_on
        "disabled" => $disabled
      );
    }
  }
```

Your JS code:

```
success: function(response)
    {
    console.log(response);

    var len = response.length;
    $("#datashow").empty();
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var id = response[i].id;
        var email = response[i].email;
        var employee_id = response[i].employee_id;
        var first_name = response[i].first_name;
        var middle_name = response[i].middle_name;
        var last_name = response[i].last_name;
        var mobile = response[i].mobile;
        var created_on = response[i].created_on;
        var disabled = response[i].disabled;
        var users = response[i].users;

        var tr_str = 
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + employee_id + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + first_name + "&nbsp;" + middle_name + "&nbsp;" + last_name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + mobile + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + created_on + "</td>" +
            "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'"  + disabled +  "value= '"  + id +  "' class='checkbox' id='select_all' ></td>" +
            "<input type='hidden' value='"  + id +  "' name='user_id' id='user_id' >" +
            "</tr>" ;


        $("#datashow").append(tr_str);
   }
}
```

Minimized PHP code:

```
$i = 1; //start at one, why not.
$html = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) {
    $disabled = '';
    if ($status == '1') 
    {
        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
    }

    $created_on = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['created_on']));

    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .=  "<td>{$i}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$row['email']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$row['employee_id']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$row['first_name']}&nbsp;{$row['middle_name']}&nbsp;{$row['last_name']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$row['mobile']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$created_on}</td>";
    $html .= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='{$row['id']}' class='checkbox' id='select_all' {$disabled}></td>";
    $html .= "<input type='hidden' value='{$row['id']}' name='user_id' id='user_id' >"; //why is this same value as above
    $html .= "</tr>" ;
    ++$i; //increment counter
}
echo $html;
```

Minimized JS code:

```
success: function(response){
    $("#datashow").append(response);
}
```

Just because it's AJAX doesn't  mean you have to return JSON, you can return plain old HTML if that is all you need. And as best I can tell, that is all you need.

If it's not all you need, you can return a combination of Data and HTML

JSON example:

```
   {
       "foo" : "bar",
       "html" : "<tr><td> .... </td></tr>"
   }
```

Then you just pull the HTML out, etc.

Having so much redundant variable assignment (localization) can make you code very hard if not impossible to read, harder to write, harder to maintain, harder to debug, harder to understand and perform worse.  None of which is good.

Be lazy and do as little work as you need to.

If you don't like it all on one line in the source code, then you can change html to an array, add the items and then implode it with a line ending

```
$html = [];
while( ... ){
  $html[] = "<tr>";
  ...
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $html);
```

This can make it a bit easier to read and debug the source code.

My rule is Readability is King.  This is a reduction of `66` lines of code, down to `28` lines (over 50%) that do basically the same thing.

**UPDATE**

Reducing the lines, will help you see things like this

```
 <tbody id=datashow>  

 </tbody>
```

Where you have HTML syntax errors, like missing `"` around your id, which probably prevents your selectors Javascript from finding your HTML elements.  And it should go without saying you should fix this.

```
<tbody id="datashow" ></tbody>
```

**UPDATE2**

Also, the "id" attribute is supposed to be unique per page/request, so your repeated use of `id='select_all'` will have undesirable effects.

Comment: Tried everything you mentioned here but sorry to say, none works the way I wanted. But really I appreciate your effort. :(

Comment: My only issue is to show the results coming out from radio selection to be paginated. Currently its showing complete list rather than 10 records per page.

Comment: That's not surprising, seeing as nothing you have even remotely looks like pagination to me.  Sorry, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Seeing as I have no idea of what you are currently trying to do, I would say that is unlikely.  I was just posting a refactoring of you current code, with all the redundancy removed.

Comment: Can we connect on email? I can provide you details over there. If its ok with you.

Comment: Sorry I don't give out my email among other information.

Comment: No issues. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I should mention here that I am using PHPMailer too in this for sending mail. I have edited that part while posting, but I don't think it can be reason for this behaviour.